# Get the bytes of generated RSA private and public key

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am generating a RSA keypair on the iphone, but how can I store the generated private and public key **in a file**? I need to encrypt the private key with AES and transmit it to my server, but I can't find any methods to get the bytes of the keys.

My code for generating the keypair:

```
-(void)generateKeyPair {
    OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
    SecKeyRef localPublicKey = NULL;
    SecKeyRef localPrivateKey = NULL;

    self.publicTag = [@"com.crap.pub" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    self.privateTag = [@"com.crap.pri" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    // Container dictionaries.
    NSMutableDictionary * privateKeyAttr = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
    NSMutableDictionary * publicKeyAttr = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];
    NSMutableDictionary * keyPairAttr = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:0];

    // Set top level dictionary for the keypair.
    [keyPairAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [keyPairAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:2048] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits];

    // Set the private key dictionary.
    [privateKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent];
    [privateKeyAttr setObject:self.privateTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    // See SecKey.h to set other flag values.

    // Set the public key dictionary.
    [publicKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent];
    [publicKeyAttr setObject:self.publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    // See SecKey.h to set other flag values.

    // Set attributes to top level dictionary.
    [keyPairAttr setObject:privateKeyAttr forKey:(__bridge id)kSecPrivateKeyAttrs];
    [keyPairAttr setObject:publicKeyAttr forKey:(__bridge id)kSecPublicKeyAttrs];

    // SecKeyGeneratePair returns the SecKeyRefs just for educational purposes.
    sanityCheck = SecKeyGeneratePair((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keyPairAttr, &localPublicKey, &localPrivateKey);
}
```

Comment: No, you don't need to send the private key encrypted to the server. Not unless you've created a very weird protocol.

Comment: It's only for simplicity, so you don't need to move a key file to new systems

Comment: Hmm, this all looks very much like PKCS#11 in Objective C. Could you try `SecItemExport` with export type `kSecFormatWrappedPKCS8`? You will need to supply a symmetric key to do the wrapping though. Thing is, normally private keys should not leave the device (or key chain) unencrypted.